# Depmod issue: modules.order and module.built in don't exist when trying to install a .deb

Tags: drivers, software-installation, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS and am in the process of installing a driver for a PCIE card, but I have an issue where it says the following:

```
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
```

So far I've tried updating and upgrading and depmod -a. Neither have worked and I'm not sure what to do.

**Edit 1:** Additional information `uname -a; lsb_release -sd; apt-cache policy linux-generic`

```
Linux saber 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
linux-generic:
Installed: 4.4.0.24.25
Candidate: 4.4.0.24.25
Version table:
*** 4.4.0.24.25 500
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 4.4.0.21.22 500
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

**Edit 2:** More info `ls /boot/*-generic`

```
/boot/abi-4.4.0-21-generic
/boot/config-4.4.0-21-generic
/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
/boot/System.map-4.4.0-21-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
/boot/abi-4.4.0-24-generic
/boot/config-4.4.0-24-generic
/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
/boot/System.map-4.4.0-24-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
```

**Edit 3:**

It's an older ioDrive from sandisk. I found it lying around in storage, I imagine it was a purchase by the previous IT admin that was never used. It's a *Sandisk ioDrive*. I'm testing to see if it still works and if it's possible to add it to one of my current servers.

`sudo lshw -c disk,storage -sanitize`

```
  *-storage UNCLAIMED
       description: Mass storage controller
       product: ioDrive
       vendor: SanDisk
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:feaf0000-feafffff
  *-storage
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: SATA Controller [RAID mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:29 ioport:d880(size=8) ioport:d800(size=4) ioport:d480(size=8) ioport:d400(size=4) ioport:d080(size=32) memory:fe7ff000-fe7ff7ff
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       logical name: scsi1
       capabilities: emulated
     *-disk
          description: ATA Disk
          product: WDC WD6400AAKS-6
          vendor: Western Digital
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: 3B01
          serial: [REMOVED]
          size: 596GiB (640GB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=7f12a981
```

**Edits 4:** Some errors I got trying to build the package. Also I'm not sure how to look at the list of dependencies for the build.

```
dh_install --sourcedir=root --fail-missing -X/usr/share/doc/iomemory-vsl
dh_install: iomemory-vsl-source missing files: usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10/iomemory-vsl.mod.c
dh_install: iomemory-vsl-source missing files: usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10/iomemory-vsl.mod.c
dh_install: iomemory-vsl-source missing files: usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10/kfio/.x86_64_cc52_libkfio.o.cmd
dh_install: iomemory-vsl-source missing files: usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10/kfio/x86_64_cc52_libkfio.o_shipped
dh_install: usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10/kfio/.x86_64_cc53_libkfio.o.cmd exists in root but is not installed to anywhere
dh_install: usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10/kfio/x86_64_cc53_libkfio.o_shipped exists in root but is not installed to anywhere
```

**Edit 5:** Post driver installation results of sudo lshw -c disk,storage -sanitize

```
  *-storage               
       description: Mass storage controller
       product: ioDrive
       vendor: SanDisk
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iodrive latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:feaf0000-feafffff
  *-usb
       description: Mass storage device
       product: Cruzer Glide
       vendor: SanDisk
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: scsi6
       version: 1.27
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          product: Cruzer Glide
          vendor: SanDisk
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sdb
          version: 1.27
          serial: [REMOVED]
          size: 14GiB (16GB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=0717f938
  *-storage
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: SATA Controller [RAID mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:30 ioport:d880(size=8) ioport:d800(size=4) ioport:d480(size=8) ioport:d400(size=4) ioport:d080(size=32) memory:fe7ff000-fe7ff7ff
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       logical name: scsi1
       capabilities: emulated
     *-disk
          description: ATA Disk
          product: WDC WD6400AAKS-6
          vendor: Western Digital
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: 3B01
          serial: [REMOVED]
          size: 596GiB (640GB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=7f12a981
```

*Result of fio-status:*

```
Found 1 ioMemory device in this system
Driver version: 3.2.10 build 1509

Adapter: Single Controller Adapter
    Fusion-io ioDrive 1.205TB, Product Number:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, SN:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, FIO SN:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    External Power: NOT connected
    PCIe Power limit threshold: 24.75W
    Connected ioMemory modules:
      fct0: Product Number:XXXXXXXXXX, SN:XXXXXXXXXXXX

fct0    Status unknown: Driver is in MINIMAL MODE:
        The firmware on this device is not compatible with the currently installed version of the driver
    ioDrive Adapter Controller, Product Number:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, SN:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
!! ---> There are active errors or warnings on this device!  Read below for details.
    Located in slot 0 Center of ioDrive Adapter Controller SN:XXXXXXXXXXX
    PCI:05:00.0
    Firmware v6.0.0, rev 105902 Public
    Geometry and capacity information not available.
    Internal temperature: 70.38 degC, max 70.87 degC

    ACTIVE WARNINGS:
        The bandwidth of the PCI slot is not optimal for the ioMemory. 
        The ioMemory is currently running in a minimal state.
```

**Edit 6:**
Related syslog:

```
(gnome-logs:3983): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkListBox with a model will ignore sort and filter functions
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, You seems running a old kernel from previous LTS release it the 1st kernel version of 14.04. Could you [edit] the question and add output of `uname -a; lsb_release -sd; apt-cache policy linux-generic` . If you meant 14.04 (not 16.04), run this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic` to reinstall that kernel. see if it works.

Comment: @Sneetsher I've updated the description with the information you requested.

Comment: @Sneetsher also, the command to reinstall the kernel did not work.

Comment: I get an error saying it was unable to locate the package "linux-image 3.13.0-24-generic" or the header.

Comment: It's been added to the description.

Comment: Then some thing wrong with driver, which package is that? What did you ran to get that error?

Comment: It's a custom driver  for a pcie ssd. I think that I've just realized the issue though. I'm running a version of Ubuntu that is newer(?) than what the driver is designed for I think. It's designed for 14.04 instead of 16.04. Is there an easy solution for this problem?

Comment: It's an older ioDrive from sandisk. I found it lying around in storage, I imagine it was a purchase by the previous IT admin that was never used. It's a Sandisk ioDrive. I'm testing to see if it still works and if it's possible  to add it to one of my current servers. Updated description again.

Comment: I edited the description with some errors I got trying to build the package. Also I'm not sure how to look at the list of dependencies for the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could find is this one, [github.com/snuf/iomemory-vsl](https://github.com/snuf/iomemory-vsl), but as the developer mention, it is not tested with last kernels, last commit was 3 months ago, you may want to give it a try.

From the errors you got, it seems you have tried to build deb package. I tried as documented in README, installing to DKMS manually. It does build fine in Ubuntu 16.04 (VBox).

```
sudo apt install linux-generic dkms git
git clone https://github.com/snuf/iomemory-vsl.git

sudo cp -r iomemory-vsl/root/usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10 /usr/src/
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dkms/iomemory-vsl/3.2.10/build
sudo ln -s /usr/src/iomemory-vsl-3.2.10 /var/lib/dkms/iomemory-vsl/3.2.10/source
sudo dkms build -m iomemory-vsl -v 3.2.10
sudo dkms install -m iomemory-vsl -v 3.2.10
```

Check:

```
$ dkms status
iomemory-vsl, 3.2.10, 4.4.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox-guest, 5.0.18, 4.4.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
...
```

You have to carry last step too, no way for me to test:

```
sudo modprobe iomemory-vsl
```

There is another repository which have the additional tools: [github.com/promisejohn/fio-driver](https://github.com/promisejohn/fio-driver).

Download & install the deb package

```
wget https://github.com/promisejohn/fio-driver/raw/master/utils/fio-util_3.2.10.1509-1.0_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i fio-util_3.2.10.1509-1.0_amd64.deb
```

Check:

```
sudo fio-status
```

Comment: It looks like the driver was installed properly but the device does not show up when I run lsblk. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fzlogic , update the answer , could you try using its own tools.

Comment: @fzlogic Could you add another output of `sudo lshw -c disk,storage -sanitize`

Comment: It looks like the speed on the pcie slot isn't fast enough for the card to run full speed, although I think that should be fine

Comment: @fzlogic, the controller hooked by driver `driver=iodrive` , seems there incompatibility with firmware version. Anyway, could you try `sudo fio-attach fct0` as i read from man page, it `Exports a fusionio device as a block device`

Comment: I get an error saying that the fct0 device could not be found.

Comment: I get an error saying that the fct0 device could not be found. I checked the syslogs and think it's a gtk issue. Updated the description.

Comment: That `Gtk-WARNING` message is not related, All  `fio-*` tools are pure CLI. Check if there a `/dev` node created with at name `find /dev/ -iregex '.*fct.*'` then use it with full path `sudo fio-attach /dev/../fct0`. To check status again `sudo fio-status`